# jQuery animate running a lot of times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problems with my animate function. I want it to just run 1 time, but it doesn't. I've tried to debug it with using `.stop();` but that didn't work either, so right now I have no idea how to solve this.

The JavaScript:

```
$(".box").hide();

$(".box").contents().not(".progress").hide();

$(".box").first().show(150, function showNext () {

    var next = $(this).next(".box");

    if (next.length > 0) {

        next.show(150, showNext);

    } else {

        $(".box").contents().not(".progress").fadeIn(800, function () {

        $(".progress").animate({

            width: 'toggle'

        }, 800);


        });

    }
});
```

The problem is easier to see at this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/etBLj/

How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when you call `$(".progress").animate()`, the animation gets executed on every element with the "progress" class **for the whole document**.  Since `showNext()` is called recursively, you end up with multiple animations for each matching element.

All you need to do is to restrict the call to `animate` to be applicable to the current element in your recursive loop.  So change to `$(this).next().animate` and it will work.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/etBLj/1/

Additionally I think the JavaScript would become easier to understand if you separated the "showing of the headers" from the "animating of the progress bars", and replaced the recursive function with a simple `each` loop.  For example: http://jsfiddle.net/etBLj/2/